# Convert string to uppercase

Tags: functional-programming, sml, smlnj

I'm programming in SML, trying to take a string and make all the characters capitalized. I'm new to SML and functional programming in general, and I can't quite get the types to match. My code looks like this:

```
fun allCaps (str) =
  let val ex = explode(str)
    in
      let fun toCaps (acc, nil: char list) = acc
            | toCaps (acc, h::t: char list) = toCaps ((acc::t), [Char.toUpper(h)])
      in
        toCaps(ex, []:char list)
      end
    end;
```

The interpreter is giving me the error

```
Error: operator and operand don't agree [tycon mismatch]
  operator domain: char * char list
  operand:         char list * char list
in expression:
  toCaps (acc :: t,Char.toUpper h :: nil)
...
  toCaps (nil: char list,ex)
```

which makes no sense to me, because it looks very explicit in the function that it is dealing with lists the entire time. Regardless, how do I initialize an empty char type to get the types matching?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> trying to take a string and make all the characters capitalized

To convert a string to uppercase,

```
- val allCaps = String.map Char.toUpper;
- allCaps "Hello World!";
> val it = "HELLO WORLD!" : string
```

For some general feedback on your code,

- *(Logical error)* `toCaps` takes two arguments, *(1)* the exploded string, and *(2)* an empty list. But you call the exploded string `acc` and pattern match against `nil`/`h::t` on the empty list; you probably want it the other way around.
- *(Type error)* You write `toCaps ((acc::t), ...)`, which means putting `acc`, a list, in front of `t`, another list. But `acc` is itself a list of the same kind as `t`; lists can only contain elements of the same kind, so they can't contain elements of their own type.
- You don't need to nest let-expressions; one let-expression can have multiple declarations:

  ```
  fun allCaps s =
    let val L = explode s
        fun toCaps ...
    in ... end
  ```
- You don't need type annotations unless it improves clarity; the compiler will infer the type.

Converting a string to a list of chars, recursing over that list, and converting the list back to a string, is inefficient but a good learning exercise in list recursion. Here's a revised version of your code:

```
fun allCaps s =
  let fun upper (c::cs) = Char.toUpper c :: upper cs
        | upper [] = []
  in implode (upper (explode s)) end
```

This function isn't [tail-recursive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33923/what-is-tail-recursion); for very long strings, `upper`'s calls to itself might eventually exhaust stack memory. You can avoid this by only making tail-calls and by keeping the accumulated result in heap memory by using a function argument as temporary storage:

```
fun allCaps s =
  let fun upper (c::cs, acc) = upper (cs, Char.toUpper c :: acc)
        | upper ([], acc) = rev acc
  in implode (upper (explode s, [])) end
```

The drawback is that when you push the first character from `c::cs` into the front of `acc`, they end up in reverse order and you need to reverse the result again before imploding it.

Either way, the string-only solution presented at the top uses less memory because it only needs to create a single string the same size as the input and loop over the indices of the input string.

Comment: Thank you so much! There is almost no information on sml, and there is even less on functions that handle lists this way. I was on the right path after posing this question by trying to reverse a reversed list, but had a lot of type issues there as well. This comment can't tell you how grateful I am.

Comment: @Allen: You're absolutely right. Most people who learn SML do so through university where textbooks are supplied with lectures and classes. Learning SML online is considerably harder.

Comment: @Allen  Learning materials: Paulson's [ML for the Working Programmer](https://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/~lp15/MLbook/pub-details.html) is now  available online in PDF form, and [this course](https://courses.cs.washington.edu/courses/cse341/17sp/) is supposed to be good (and includes lecture videos).